# Issue with using [display-posts] shortcode on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I am having an issue finding any way to display a single post on the woocommerce checkout specifically on a payment plugin, I use other shortcodes in these gateways and they work perfectly.
However when I try using some display post shortcodes it doesn’t work at all and instead shows up as text.
Example of my issue - i edit and put in the shortcode [display-posts] and instead of displaying the posts it simply displays [display-posts].

I have tried using multiple shortcode plugins and even tried creating my own. The main one I have tried to use is [display-posts] with the plug-in. I always put it in my themes functions.php as well!
I have tried these short codes on the regular Wordpress pages that I have that are published and have found I have the same issue, so I don’t believe it’s the placement I want the shortcode to appear at. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To make all the posts display you can create a custom shortcode and the shortcode which you are using is **[display-posts] is not default WordPress** in build shortcode. To have your same shortcode run **please install the below plugin:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Then you [display-posts] shortcode will work or another solution is custom shortcode as I mentioned above.

Please let me know if find any issues.

Thanks.